# Passing parameter to controller action through routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Rails: How do I pass custom params to a controller method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150254/rails-how-do-i-pass-custom-params-to-a-controller-method)

I am wondering if it possible to pass parameter to controller action through routes. I have a one generic action method which I want to call for various routes. No, I can't use wildcard in my route.

```
match '/about' => 'pages#show'
match '/terms' => 'pages#show'
match '/privacy' => 'pages#show'
```

I am looking for something like:

```
match '/about' => 'pages#show', :path => "about"
match '/terms' => 'pages#show', :path => "terms"
match '/privacy' => 'pages#show', :path => "privacy"
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150254/rails-how-do-i-pass-custom-params-to-a-controller-method/12150277#12150277

Comment: @Istvan Please don't edit out the old-style generated duplicate links text. Reopening should be done through the review queue/reopen votes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the closing/voting system doesn't work as expected. People shouldn't be allowed to cast closing votes if they are not an expert in the relevant topic.
What are these old-style generated duplicate link text btw?

Comment: Btw are you a moderator? If not, then please don't revert my edit.

Comment: @IstvánUjj-Mészáros In the old-style, the system "edited" the question to add the duplicate link, in the new-style they are in a separate block that can only be removed by reopening. And in case you were not aware yet, SO is community moderated, with elected moderators for exception handling. In any case, I reverted your edit because it removes the necessary context of the closure. As an aside, your position I shouldn't have done so could also be reversed: given you aren't a moderator, you shouldn't have made that edit.

Comment: Yeah, there is a reason I am not active on SO. It started to die 10 years ago and didn't become any better since that. It is so sad that google is still showing it up ahead of other sites.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
match '/about' => 'pages#show', :defaults => { :id => 'about' }
match '/terms' => 'pages#show', :defaults => { :id => 'terms' }
match '/privacy' => 'pages#show', :defaults => { :id => 'privacy' }
```

*if* you can't for some reason just follow the standard convention of

```
match '/:id' => 'pages#show'
```

Comment: Also works with scopes: `scope :user, as: 'user', defaults: { scope: :user } do`.