# RAILS: Rendering views from the same controller based on the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have two routes (defined in my config/routes.rb)

```
match 'compare'     => 'front_office#search_by_id', :via => :get, :as => :front_office_compare
match 'full_report' => 'front_office#search_by_id', :via => :get, :as => :front_office_full_report
```

I would like to know how I can tell my controller to render the view based on my route, without adding a parameter on my URL.

Based on this [Question&Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219436/passing-parameter-to-controller-action-through-routes) I Managed to get the result I want with

```
match 'compare'     => 'front_office#search_by_id', :via => :get, :as => :front_office_compare,     :defaults => { :render => 'compare' }
match 'full_report' => 'front_office#search_by_id', :via => :get, :as => :front_office_full_report, :defaults => { :render => 'full_report' }
```

And in my controller I defined my action as:

```
  def search_by_id
    render :action => (params[:render] || "full_report")
  end
```

But is this a Good Practice or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: this does not really make a lot of sense. why arent you mapping it to two different actions in the first place?

Comment: @phoet  Cause the data is the same,  only the way we display it will change.  Ex.  A Summary vs Detail report.

Comment: @JudgeProphet then i think you need to change your action name to make more meaningful based on your  requirement. `search_by_id` seems some what similar to `show` action now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating different routes for each category you are making for simplifying you can write it like:

```
# config/routes.rb 

get ":category", to: "front_office#search_by_id", as: 'front_office', constraints: {category: /(compare|full_report)/}
```

the above routes looks for `/compare` and `/full_report` and this will call **search_by_id** action in **front_office** controller.

then inside the controller do as follows:

```
def search_by_id
  render params[:category]
end
```

`params[:category]` will hold the slug values which we passed through the URL